# How to resolve 403 Forbidden error when uploading to S3

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, http-status-code-403, dropzone

I'm setting up a vuejs / DropzoneJS - app loosely based on kfei's vue-s3-dropzone app. It's designed to upload files (by using a PUT method) to AWS S3 serverlessly using a AWS Lambda function and a AWS S3 bucket.I'm basically getting a XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status and a 403 error code when I try to upload an image to the S3 bucket.  Is there anything I can do to

This is what I've did:

1. created an S3 bucket
2. Set up a bucket policy and a CORS configuration in the S3 bucket settings:

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReMeG.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoFXa.png)
3. Created a lambda function that is supposed to sign a URL which allows a PUT upload for each file to S3, with the Role executing the Lambda having a PutObject and PutObjectAcl permission on the S3 bucket:

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsQZT.png)
4. Set up an Api Gateway API with an OPTIONS method (to pass the preflight check) and a PUT method with these CORS settings:

   b. The OPTIONS method has a Mock backend integration with the Integration Response returning the following:

   Access-Control-Allow-Headers    'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,x-requested-with' 
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods    ‘PUT,OPTIONS'
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'

   c. The PUT method has:

   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
5. In AWS Api Gateway: Setup a api-key and a usage plan

The lambda code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var bucketName = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME;

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    if (!event.hasOwnProperty('contentType')) {
        context.fail({ err: 'Missing contentType' });
    }

    if (!event.hasOwnProperty('filePath')) {
        context.fail({ err: 'Missing filePath' });
    }

    var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: event.filePath,
        Expires: 3600,
        ContentType: event.contentType
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, url) => {
        if (err) {
            context.fail({ err });
        } else {
            context.succeed({ url });
        }
    });
};
```

Expected: Successful upload of files
Actual: Possible CORS issues.

Comment: if you're seeing 403 response, cors header won't be served by S3 and you'll see the cors error as well, the problem is with permission.

Answer (score 0):

**getSignedUrl** will work fine if you were uploading the file from an API client like Postman or a Node.js server, but as you state you are seeing a preflight check fail, I'm assuming you are using some kind of HTML form & frontend js.

From the [AWS JavaScript SDK Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) regarding getSignedUrl:

> Note: Not all operation parameters are supported when using pre-signed
>   URLs. Certain parameters, such as SSECustomerKey, ACL, **Expires**,
>   ContentLength, or Tagging must be provided as headers when sending a
>   request. **If you are using pre-signed URLs to upload from a browser and
>   need to use these fields, see createPresignedPost()**.

As you are setting the 'Expires' param  when calling getSignedUrl and are sending from the browser, you need to use [createPresignedPost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property) instead of getSignedUrl in your Lambda code.

You will then need to POST instead of PUT from the browser to S3.

**NB**: Remember to update your CORS rules for S3 with POST